# Wordpress Datatrans Ajax implementation

Tags: ajax, wordpress, payment

I'm trying to implement a creditcard payment service (of datatrans.ch) into a wordpress based site. Datatrans offers an Ajax API, which you can take a look at here:

[Datatrans Ajax API](https://www.datatrans.ch/Showcase/Authorisation/Ajax-API/Ajax-API/)

[Example Code](http://www.datatrans.ch/CMS4.ASPX?NID=2001&CID=3020)

I copy/pasted the example code and saved it inside a html file on my machine. Running it works properly. In the next step I tried implementing it in wordpress by creating the following function:

```
function datatrans_payment_ajax($lang, $currency, $amount) {

$merchant_id = 101...; // ... on my machine it is numeric of course ;)

wp_deregister_script('datatrans-ajax');
wp_register_script('datatrans-ajax', 'https://pilot.datatrans.biz/upp/ajax/api.js?merchantId='.$merchant_id, false);
wp_enqueue_script('datatrans-ajax');

?>

<noscript>
    <p class="err">
    JavaScript is disabled in your browser.<br/>
    This showcase requires JavaScript.
    </p>
</noscript>

<div>

    <h3>Step 1: Ajax UPP.paymentRequest(...)</h3>

    <form id="uppform">
        <fieldset>

        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="<?php echo $lang; ?>"/>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="550">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Merchant Id :</td>
                <td style="width: 10px">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" size="20" name="merchantId" value="<?php echo $merchant_id; ?>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="left">Amount :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" size="20" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>"/> (= 10.00) 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="left">Currency :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" size="20" name="currency" value="<?php echo $currency; ?>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="left">Card Number :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" size="24" name="cardNumber" value="4242424242424242"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="left">Expiry :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="text" size="4" name="expm" value="12"/>&nbsp; 
                    <input type="text" size="4" name="expy" value="15"/>&nbsp; (MM/YY) 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="left">CVV code :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" size="4" name="cvv" value="123"/>&nbsp; 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display: none;">
                <td align="left">Process mode :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="radio" name="mode" id="auto" value="auto" checked="checked"/> <label for="auto">Automatic 3D ACS call using API</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="mode" id="manual" value="manual"/> <label for="manual">Manual redirection to 3D ACS</label>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="button" class="button"
                    onclick="callPayment()" value="send"/><span class="buttend"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        </fieldset>            
    </form>

    <div id="frameHolder"></div>
    <div id="response" style="width: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="step2" style="display: none;">
        <h3>Step 2: XML authorizeSplit (server-2-server request)</h3>
        <form action="https://pilot.datatrans.biz/upp/jsp/XML_authorizeSplitEx.jsp" method="post" target="_parent">
            <fieldset>
                <textarea style="width: 400px; height: 150px;" name="xmlRequest"></textarea>
                <div>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="send"/><span class="buttend"></span>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var mode;
    var params;
    function callPayment()
    {
        mode = $("input[name=mode]:checked").val();

        // read form values
        params = {
                merchantId: $("input[name=merchantId]").val(),
                cardNumber: $("input[name=cardNumber]").val(),
                expy: $("input[name=expy]").val(),
                expm: $("input[name=expm]").val(),
                cvv: $("input[name=cvv]").val(),
                currency: $("input[name=currency]").val(),
                amount: $("input[name=amount]").val()
        }

        // call paymentRequest, response will be received in responseCallback
        if ( mode == "auto" )
        {
            params.returnUrl = "https://pilot.datatrans.biz/upp/ajax/sample-merchant-return-page.html";
            UPP.paymentRequest( params,     responseCallback, frameCallback );
        }
        else
        if ( mode == "manual" )
        {
            UPP.paymentRequest( params,     responseCallback );
        }
    };

    function frameCallback()
    {
        // create iframe and add it to document
        var iframe = $("<iframe/>").attr( "id", "paymentIFrame" ).width( 390 ).height( 400 );    
        $("#frameHolder").append( iframe );

        $("form#uppform").hide(); //hide the form

        return iframe[0];
    };

    function responseCallback( response ) 
    {     
        var responseElm = $("#response");

        responseElm
            .empty()
            .append( "<h4>Ajax response:</h4>")
            .append( $("<div/>").text("status: " + response.status) )
            .append( $("<div/>").text("uppTransactionId: " + response.uppTransactionId) );

        if ( JSON.stringify )
            responseElm
                .append( $("<div/>").html( "Complete JSON response: " + JSON.stringify( response ).replace( /,/g, ", ") ) )


        if ( mode == "auto" )
        {
            if ( response.status == "success" )
            {
                // This step will be done server-2-server
                $("#step2 textarea").val(
                        "<<?php?>?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n" + 
                        "<authorizationSplit version=\"1\">\n" + 
                        "<body merchantId=\"" + $("input[name=merchantId]").val() + "\">\n" +  
                        "<transaction refno=\"to_be_filled\">\n" + 
                        "  <request>\n" + 
                        "    <uppTransactionId>" + response.uppTransactionId + "</uppTransactionId>\n" +  
                        "    <amount>" + $("input[name=amount]").val() + "</amount>\n" + 
                        "    <currency>" + $("input[name=currency]").val() + "</currency>\n" + 
                        "   </request>\n" + 
                        "  </transaction>\n" + 
                        "</body>\n" + 
                        "</authorizationSplit>"
                    );
                $("#step2").show();
                $("#uppform").hide();
            }

            if ( response.is3DEnrolled ) // close/remove the iframe
            {
                $("#paymentIFrame").remove();
            }
        }
        else
        if ( mode == "manual" ) // manual mode used, browser has to be redirected to ACSURL
        {        
            if ( response.is3DEnrolled && response.status == "success" )
            {
                responseElm.append( $("<div/>").html( "Redirecting page to ACS in 3 seconds..." ) );

                setTimeout( function() {
                    params.uppTransactionId = response.uppTransactionId;
                    params.errorUrl = "https://pilot.datatrans.biz/upp/merchant/errorPage.jsp";
                    params.returnUrl = "https://pilot.datatrans.biz/upp/merchant/successPage.jsp";
                    window.parent.location = response.ACSURL + "?" + $.param( params );
                }, 3000 );
            }
        }
    };
    </script>

</div>
```

When I run it, I receive an error status code 1003, saying that the uppTransactionId is undefined which should result from the responseCallback. So I guess it has something to do with the usual processing of Ajax calls in wordpress which must go through the admin-ajax.php file in the wp-admin folder!? I am not sure how to cut this datatrans implementation into pieces to make it fit the wordpress Ajax processing. Furthermore I would like to know if you think that my guess is even right regarding what causes the error?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: [Dragi Postolovski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7671139) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67029713) saying "I think this can help with your problem. it shows you how to create a test account and how to use the APIs. [https://projectsengine.com/datatrans-payments-apis-developers-manual-in-php/](https://projectsengine.com/datatrans-payments-apis-developers-manual-in-php/)"

Answer (score 0):

Ask them to open test account for you, and then you could test with your MerchantID on pilot servers with all features. If you copy/paste code from their examples i think this will not work. Those are just examples of implementation.

You can try to use `Merchant-ID:1000011011` but this is shared from all users, so you cannot set landing redirect pages (on success, on error)

Also check what encoding you use:

- UTF-8 encoding: **/jsp/upStart.jsp**
- ISO encoding: **/jsp/upStartIso.jsp**

And most common mistake is price format, if you price is 15.25 you need to send 1525.
Also if you wish to use 3D secure, you need to activate this in datatrans backend.